# Python count number of 1's in every 12 bits

Tags: python-3.x

I have 60 bits of binary number and would like to calculate # of 1's in every 12 bits.

Input is 64 digits and I discard most significant 4 bits to keep 60 bits. Then, calculate # of 1's in 60 bits.

Currently, I have hamming weight(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight) representation, which does return # of 1's in 60 bits. But, I would like to extend it to every x th bits and x would be a parameter.

Would anyone share ideas how to implement it?

```
def hamming_weight(y):
    x = y & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF

    x -= (x >> 1) & 0x5555555555555555
    x = (x & 0x3333333333333333) + ((x >> 2) & 0x3333333333333333)
    x = (x + (x >> 4)) & 0x0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f
    return ((x * 0x0101010101010101) & 0xffffffffffffffff ) >> 56
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution using `itertools`. I left some debug prints in there to show how it works. It takes any integer, the number of bytes in that integer (for padding purposes), and and the group size you want. Be aware that the last group may contain less than group_size numbers.

```
import itertools

# https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes
def grouper(n, iterable, fillvalue=None):
    "grouper(3, 'ABCDEFG', 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return itertools.zip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)


def count_ones(num, total_bits, group_size):
    # Turn the original number to a string of ones and zeros
    num_bin_str = bin(num)[2:]

    # That discards any zeros that are supposed to be on the left
    # so pad it with those if necessary
    padded_bin_str = '0' * (total_bits - len(num_bin_str)) + num_bin_str
    print(padded_bin_str)

    for g in grouper(group_size, padded_bin_str, 0):
        print(g)
        yield sum(map(int, filter(None, g)))


for i in count_ones(0b10011, 8, 2):
    print(i)
```

The output for a number `0b10011` which is really an 8 bit number for a group size of two:

```
00010011
('0', '0')
0
('0', '1')
1
('0', '0')
0
('1', '1')
2
```

Here's how I think it would work with a 64 bit number that you want to chop down to 60 bits and count 1's

```
# So, starting with a 64 bit integer (I'm just picking one at random here)
# make sure that the number isn't bigger than 64 bits, otherwise I'm not sure if the following trick will work
import random
n = random.randint(0, 2**64 - 1)
# change the first 4 bits to 0 so they don't screw every thing up
# basically I want to generate 64 bits of 1's, 
# discard the leftmost 4, and & it with n
# check this- not sure it's 100% correct
n &= ((2**64 - 1) >> 4)

# Now, I should have a large number, but the first ones are 0s

for ones in count_ones(n, 60, 8):
    print(ones)
```

And the output of that is:

```
000000001011001000010110010000101100100001011001000010110010
('0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0')
0
('1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0')
4
('0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0')
3
('0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0')
2
('1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0')
3
('0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1')
4
('0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1')
3
('0', '0', '1', '0', 0, 0, 0, 0)
1 # Note that we ran out of bits before group size so it's filling it with zeros
```

Comment: Thanks, This will work. I am applying this function to dataframe that I've loaded from. Will use this function.

Comment: Glad to help! Just be sure to test it!  Can you accept the answer?

Comment: Sure, I have one more question, though. To keep 56 bites and discard 4 left most significant bits, if I apply 'num = num >> 4', it is saying an error "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for >>: 'float' and 'int'". Is there any other way that I can do this?

Comment: `num` is a float. You can't do bit shift operations (`<<` or `>>`) on a float. They don't really make sense. You have to cast it to an int : `num = int(num)` (which means you forfeit anything after the decimal point), then do the bit shift.

Comment: so I casted it to an int. No error produced.; But not sure whether data is not lost. I am applying this function to pandas dataframe structure.

Comment: if your float has anything after the decimal point, that will be lost. I'm curious- why are you doing this anyway?

Answer (score 1):

The bitmath technique can be adapted to make horizontal sums of 12-bit chunks fairly easily, but it is not easy to make it generic in the size of the chunk. It's easy for power-of-two sizes and in general it can be done, but not easily. Assuming the focus is 12-bit chunks, you could derive it like this.

- 12 is divisible by 2, so making the sums of adjacent pairs is fine (in the sense that it never sums "across" a chunk-boundary), the `5..` step can stay. Now the problem turns into "horizontal sums of 2-bit numbers in 6-item chunks".
- 6 is still divisible by 2, so making sums of nibbles is fine too, the `3..` step can stay.
- 3 is not divisible by 2, but 3 is small, just do a 3-part sum.

In the hsums-of-nibbles that we have from the second step, every nibble is the popcnt of its bits. So their width is 4 bits, but the maximum value is 4. Adding 3 of them in-place (without making more space in advance) still works, the max is only 12, no carry into the next nibble. So the same technique can be used, but summing 3 nibbles and with a different mask:

```
x = (x + (x >> 4) + (x >> 8)) & 0xf00f00f00f00f00f
```

Actually the top `f` is not needed in your case and perhaps unwanted, if you leave it out you're implicitly doing a count of 60 bits (without having to mask the 4 top bits off explicitly). In general it would be there.

In total (not tested)

```
def hamming_weight(y):
    x = y & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF

    x -= (x >> 1) & 0x5555555555555555
    x = (x & 0x3333333333333333) + ((x >> 2) & 0x3333333333333333)
    return (x + (x >> 4) + (x >> 8)) & 0xf00f00f00f00f00f
```

You can see from the construction why it doesn't generalize well, a chunk size with large prime factors would not be decomposable this neatly. It can still be done, but then you have to use extra masking to avoid summing across chunk boundaries, and you get into some annoying situations with unequal sub-field sizes. Computing the necessary masks is not that easy, probably not worth doing at runtime. For example, for a chunk size of 7 you could do something like (not tested)

```
# sums of adjacent bits, with extra bit summed into the top
x = (x & 0x952a54a952a54a95) + ((x & 0x2a54a952a54a952a) >> 1) + ((x & 0x4081020408102040) >> 2)
# sums of 3-in-a-row nibs, since there are only 3 left per chunk anyway
x = (x & 0x83060c183060c183) + ((x & 0x0c183060c183060c) >> 2) + ((x & 0x3060c183060c1830) >> 4)
```

.. which could perhaps be simplified some.

Comment: I'll have to create a new function other than reusing my previous code. Since it's not easy to fix it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will work if your split amount is evenly divisible to your total number of bits:

```
bits = str(x)
#number of ranges to check... your example would be 60/12=5
for i in range(len(bits) / splitNum):                     
    sum=0    
    #number of characters to check for '1'...your example would be indexes[0,12),[12,24)...[48,60)                
    for j in range(i*splitNum, i*splitNum + splitNum): 
        if bits[j] == '1':
            sum+=1
    print(sum) #could also add to a list here, etc
```

Or even simpler:

```
bits = str(x)
sum = 0
for i in range(len(bits)):
    if bits[i] == '1':
        sum+=1
    if i % splitNum == 0:
        print(sum) #or something else
        sum = 0
```

I hope these concepts solved or at least got you on the right path to your solution :D